# Returning value type from compiled expression

Tags: c#, lambda, boxing

I have some very dynamic code that was originally using reflection with `Type.GetProperty` and `PropertyInfo.GetValue` to get values from an object. Then I read this about the performance of `GetValue`:

https://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/getting-data-through-reflection-getvalue/

And decided to try and improve things by creating and caching delegates like they do in the post. So I created something like this:

```
private Delegate MakeAccessDelegate(PropertyInfo p)
{
    var delType = typeof(Func<,>);
    var genType = delType.MakeGenericType(p.DeclaringType, p.PropertyType);
    var mi = p.GetAccessors().First();
    return Delegate.CreateDelegate(genType, mi);
}
```

But, because I don't know the type of the delegate, I'm forced to use `DynamicInvoke`, which is, on the bright side, no worse that `GetValue`, but doesn't seem to be any better either.

So I searched a little and came across this question and answer:

[alternative for using slow DynamicInvoke on muticast delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083618/alternative-for-using-slow-dynamicinvoke-on-muticast-delegate)

The accepted answer suggests using a compiled delegate and that sounds like something that could help a lot. Since my methods are just property getters, I need to change it a little and came up with this (I don't know anything about expression trees, so I'm flying a little blind here):

```
delegate object CachedMethodDelegate(object instance);

private CachedMethodDelegate MakeAccessDelegate(PropertyInfo p)
{
    var methodInfo = p.GetAccessors().First();
    var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<CachedMethodDelegate>(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.Convert(instance, methodInfo.DeclaringType),
            methodInfo
            ),
        instance
        );

    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

And this seems to work. Except for one small wrinkle. If the property is a value type (e.g. `double` or `datetime`), then it can't create the lambda. It throws an `ArgumentException` on the line `var lambda = ...` with the error:

```
Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]' cannot be used 
for return type 'System.Object'
```

Clearly it's not able to handle the automatic boxing and unboxing of value types. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `Expression.Convert` on the result of `Expression.Call` and convert it to `object`.  This will result in a boxing operation in the event that the type needs to be boxed.